# Puppet server hostname does not match certificate - can't authenticate. How to disable puppet authentication?

Tags: ssl, authentication, puppet, puppetmaster

I am having issues with getting the puppet agent to authenticate the master.

On the agent, I first did 
`sudo puppet agent --test`

```
info: Creating a new SSL key for m-agent-2
info: Caching certificate for ca
info: Creating a new SSL certificate request for m-agent-2
info: Certificate Request fingerprint (md5): 43:30:57:53:5B:20:F7:12:CD:94:59:17:12:28:68:A4
```

Then on the master I did `sudo puppet cert list` and got

```
"m-agent-2" (43:30:57:53:5B:20:F7:12:CD:94:59:17:12:28:68:A4)
```

Then I did `sudo puppet cert sign m-agent-2`, which returned

```
notice: Signed certificate request for m-agent-2
notice: Removing file Puppet::SSL::CertificateRequest m-agent-2 at                 
'/var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/requests/m-agent-2.pem'
```

Then I did `sudo puppet agent --test`, which returned

```
info: Caching certificate for m-agent-2
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Server hostname 'puppet' did not match server certificate; expected master-node-1
warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
err: Could not send report: Server hostname 'puppet' did not match server certificate; expected master-node-1
```

The conf file contains the line in both `certname = master-node-1` in both `[main]` and `[master]` sections. I have regenerated the master's certificate by doing

```
sudo find $(puppet master --configprint ssldir) -name "$(puppet master --configprint certname).pem" -delete   
sudo puppet master --no-daemonize --verbose
```

Also, my /etc/hosts file contains the lines `10.20.32.10 learn.localdomain   learn puppet.localdomain puppet` and I can ping both puppet and puppet.learn from the agent.

However I still get the same issue. Is there some way to fix this. Or disable authentication in puppet all together. Both the master and the slave nodes are running Ubuntu 12.04 and I am running puppet 2.7.11. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your client's expecting the master to have the hostname `puppet`, per its `server` configuration in `puppet.conf` - that's the default, so if you don't have a `server` configured then it's using `puppet`.  The master's SSL certificate must be valid for that name, or the client will refuse to connect.

Normally, the master generates a certificate that's valid for its own hostname and the `puppet` hostname, by using subject alternative names.. but having an explicit `certname` in the master's `puppet.conf` might be overriding this.  Verify by checking `puppet cert --list master-node-1` - it should have something like `(alt names: "puppet")` displayed after the certificate's thumbprint.

Correct this by either having your client pointed to the real hostname using its `server` config, or by having the server's cert valid for the hostname `puppet`.

Comment: or simply you're executing puppet without sudo or root...